# Java: Adding two random array elements for each category of a custom arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I am providing the user with two random videos for each category they have selected.

I have an ArrayList of strings for the user preferences.

I also have an ArrayList of all of the videos in the database.

So I am trying to search through each of those category preferences one by one and find two random videos that fit into it those category.

I have implemented a solution that works (On a small dataset). But I am not sure it is optimal method considering there will soon be 500 videos, 50 categories and the user will be able to select 5 category preferences:

This is how I worked it out:

```
    //Create a new array to store the videos
    ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create counter for the position in the user preference array
    int userPrefernceArrayIndex = 0;

    // Create counter for number of successful category guesses
    int numberOfSuccessfulGuesses = 0;

    // Keep running until we have 2 videos for each of the user preferences
    while (videos.size() < MainActivity.userPrefrencesStaticArraylist.size() * 2){

        // Generate a random integer to get an entry random integer from the database array
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomAlarmVidInt = rand.nextInt(MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.size());

        // Find the category of the random video that was chosen
        String categoryForRandomGuess = MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.get(randomAlarmVidInt).getVideoCategory();

        // Find the current user video category we are testing for
        String currentCategoryPreference = MainActivity.userPrefrencesStaticArraylist.get(userPrefernceArrayIndex);

        // Check if category of the random video we got is the same as the category user
        // preference we are testing for
        if (categoryForRandomGuess.equals(currentCategoryPreference)){

            // If it the the preference and the random video categories match add it to the video array
            videos.add(MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.get(randomAlarmVidInt));
            numberOfSuccessfulGuesses++;

            // If the number of successful guesses is divisible by two then we have added two correct videos
            // for that category so iterate to the next category
            if (numberOfSuccessfulGuesses % 2 == 0){
                userPrefernceArrayIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Because of the possibility for problems I hardly ever use a while loop or random unless necessary. I also see that guessing the number may not be the best solution memory wise. So I just want to make sure I am doing it the best way to avoid issues.

Thanks for your help

Comment: For 500 videos and 5 category preferences I would expect it to work OK. In any case, wise men say don’t try to optimize until you know for a fact that you are having a performance problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks

Comment: @NicholasMuir Feel free for any queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can **optimize your solution** as following:

Currently your iterations of `while loop` are getting wasted: Say `categoryForRandomGuess` and `currentCategoryPreference` both are equal to `"Category 1"`.

So `numberOfSuccessfulGuesses` becomes 1, but `userPrefernceArrayIndex` stays `0`. So if in next iteration if `categoryForRandomGuess` is `"Category 4"`, the iteration will be wasted even if `currentCategoryPreference` can become equal to `"Category 4"` **for some other value of userPrefernceArrayIndex, that is value other than 0**.

I would Suggest using a `HashMap<String,Integer>` where `String` stores the video category and `Integer` stores the index of first video found in database of the category.

if the `Integer value` is -1, it will mean we have 2 videos and we are done with the category.

Now you can eliminate the variable `userPrefernceArrayIndex` and your code will be a lot shorter

So your code would be:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> mymap = new HashMap<>();

while (videos.size() < MainActivity.userPrefrencesStaticArraylist.size() * 2)
{
    // Generate a random integer to get an entry random integer from the database array
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomAlarmVidInt =  rand.nextInt(MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.size());

    // Find the category of the random video that was chosen
    String categoryForRandomGuess = MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.get(randomAlarmVidInt).getVideoCategory();

    //check if the hashmap has the category
    if(mymap.get(categoryForRandomGuess) == null)
     {
      mymap.put(categoryForRandomGuess,randomAlarmVidInt);
      videos.add(MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.get(randomAlarmVidInt));
     }
    else
    {//-1 means we already have 2 videos of the category.
     if(mymap.get(categoryForRandomGuess) == -1)
      continue;
     //if following condition is true, then its a duplicate video
     if(mymap.get(categoryForRandomGuess) == randomAlarmVidInt)
      continue;//skip the rest of loop and get new value of randomAlarmVidInt      
     else 
      {
       mymap.put(categoryForRandomGuess,-1);//second video added
       videos.add(MainActivity.allVideosFromDatabaseStaticArray.get(randomAlarmVidInt));
      }
    } 

   }
```